# How to install radian on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python

I am trying to install the radian R terminal on Ubuntu 22.04. The instructions on the project's [github page](https://github.com/randy3k/radian) suggest to install it using pip, which I did:

```bash
pip3 install -U radian
```

The install was successful:

```bash
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting radian
  Using cached radian-0.6.4-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.39 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from radian) (0.3.39)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from radian) (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.1,>=3.0.15 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from radian) (3.0.33)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.1,>=3.0.15->radian) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.39->radian) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.10.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.39->radian) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.10.0->rchitect<0.4.0,>=0.3.39->radian) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: radian
  WARNING: The script radian is installed in '/home/user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed radian-0.6.4
```

However, when I try to run it, the command is not found. What's going on here? Why can't I run radian after the install?

```bash
user@computer:~$ radian
radian: command not found
```

I tried adding /home/user/.local/bin to $PATH and that did not fix it:

```bash
user@computer:~$ echo $PATH
home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried adding /home/user/.local/bin to $PATH and that did not fix it:
>
> ```
> user@computer:~$ echo $PATH
> home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bi> n:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
> ```

Was also searching for answer, and you have the right fix (add `~/.local/bin` to path) but you have a typo. You are missing a `/` before `home` on the first line of the path.